# how do you capture multiline output from a perl `command` call?

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that I can pass arguments to from the command line and it will output the results. I have tried to capture those results:

```
$systemReturn = `$cmd`;
```

with only a response of an empty string. I know this file outputs a multi-line string. Obvously there is a diffirent method needed to capture it. Does anyone know how I would get this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command probably outputs to stderr, not stdout.  Try

```
$systemReturn = `$cmd 2>&1`;
```

Comment: Thank you, It is outputting stderr not stdout. So am I safe to assume it will redirect the whole output to a single string?

Comment: Yes.  or use @array= to have separate lines.

Comment: + one could capture and print the string output from `$cmd 2>&1` to a logger ( or logging func )

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking up on [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture%3a%3aTiny) or IO::CaptureOutput as well. It makes it easier and more portable to catch the output, split or join STDOUT and STDERR, check for success, and even tee.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
@systemReturn = `$cmd`;
```